# JQuery Wrap Table Cell With Responsive Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint table `table#layoutsTable` that is generated automatically. I am able to wrap the entire table with a `div.row` element. I am trying to add individual classes to `td` elements with `columns` + `.large-#` elements based on the cell's width property. Here's the condensed html markup:

```
<span id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
    ...
        <div class="row">
            <table id="layoutsTable" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="vertical-align: top;>
                        <td style="width: 66.6%;">
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 33.3%;">
                            ...
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    ...
</span>
```

The `<div class="row">` element is already wrapped into the markup manually with jquery and the attempt to add classes to the indiviual cells in this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table#layoutsTable').wrap('<div class="row">'); //operates properly

    $('table#layoutsTable td').each(function(){
        var width = $(this).css('width');
        console.log(width);
        if(width === '66.6%'){
            $(this).addClass('large-8 columns');
        }

        if(width === '33.3%'){
            $(this).addClass('large-4 columns');
        }
    });
});
```

an alternative approach (although a limited option for responsiveness) is to simply add these responsive classes to the cells themselves. However, this would not be preferred.

Comment: Wrapping the cells would give a corrupt markup, since you can't use div as a child of tr. Anyway - since these classes are just CSS- why don't you do this in CSS - apply the rules to the cells, add display-type: 'inline' to the table and tr, and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not wrap a td with a div. It defeats the purpose of having the table structure. Just add the class right to the td.

```
$(this).addClass("large-8 columns");
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I figured this would be the only solution, unfortunately, with SharePoint, tables are the automatically generated structure of the data, i was merely trying to work around having to modify the specific table elements themselves. However, this doesn't complete the proper function to assign those classes to the table cells. I've modified the question slightly to pursue a more defined answer.